# How do you transfer a file from a local Mac to a remote Linux machine

Tags: linux, macos, mac, command-line, file-transfer

How do you transfer a file from a local Mac to a remote Linux machine

Comment: More info please? Do you have file sharing set up anywhere? What's your setup like? What's going on? Where am I? OH GOD MAKE IT STOP

Comment: Load it into a big cannon, and fire it in the Linux machine's general direction. I imagine your linux machine as Optimus Prime (wasn't he running linux?), and autobots generally have good enough reflexes to catch an airborne file.

Comment: @scottl - Best. reply. EVER!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What options do you have to connect to the remote Linux machine?

FTP? Use an FTP Client.
SSH? Use an FTP Client that support SFTP or use `scp`
Web? Host it somewhere and use `wget` or `curl`

The possibilities are endless.

Comment: In the end I used SCP with a private key.

Answer (score 2):

```
rsync --partial --progress -avzr --exclude '.DS_Store' you@macip:path you@linuxip:path
```

Explanation:

- `--partial`: don't delete partially transferred files if stopped
- `--progress`: show progress during sync
- `a`: archive
- `v`: verbose
- `z`: compression
- `r`: recursive
- `--exclude '.DS_Store'`: skip DS_Store files

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [IP over Carrier Pigeon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers) setup.  Be careful of dropped bits (literally).

Comment: Hmm, i'd have given you a point if you linked to the official RFC :)

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floppy_disk + Physical movement = Super User Solution